# Regex between a specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to get and replace Strings within a specific pattern: `$here is a string$` should be replaced with `$$$here is a string$$$`. However there can also occurences of `$$` or `$$here is text$$` which should **not** be replaced.

I use this: `\$.+?(\$)` search-pattern and it avoids `$$` these empty dollar signs pretty well, however it still finds these: `$$text$$` which it shouldn't. (Well due to the nature of it, it actually finds `$$text$`, but that's not really better)

I need to find a way to forbid another `$` to appear after the last `$` (probably using regex negations), but how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you worried about the following case: `$string$otherString$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have lookarounds available:

```
(?<!\$)\$[^$]+\$(?!\$)
```

EDIT: Including comments

```
(?<!\$)          # Negative lookbehind.  The character before this cannot
                 #  be a $ (it can be the beginning of the string since
                 #  this is a zero-width assertion
\$               # literal $
[^$]             # Character class meaning "anything but a $"
+                # Match one or more of this character class
\$               # literal $
(?!\$)           # Negative lookahead.  Similar to the lookbehind, but
                 # this cannot be *followed* by $
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Would you mind explaining what this is doing exactly? - Edit: Thanks!

Comment: @TwarlightSpikle I edited my answer to include an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting on any character after the dollar sign.  instead, try to do any character BUT the dollar sign.  You can also use curly brackets to limit the number of matches to 1.

```
\$[^$]+?\${1}
```

`{n,m}` matches the pattern between `n` and `m` times

`{n}` matches the pattern exactly `n` times

`[^...]` matches all characters that do not match the given character set

Comment: `/\${1}/` matches `$$`

Comment: Good point, that would match the part inside []:  [$string$$]other string$.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actualy, now that I'm thinking of it, this doesn't happen because I'm matching all but `$` before it, and only allowing one.  So I think the only issue might be the case where you have `$string$string$`.  But I could be wrong...

Comment: Seems like mine works (without lookarounds) http://refiddle.com/h19 (I added the case to avoid `\n` for demonstration) but if I'm missing something, please let me know!!