# How to have bold characters for multiple substrings wrapped inside a pattern with Jetpack Compose Text like Telegram or WhatsApp

Tags: android, regex, android-jetpack-compose-text

What i aim to do is to create a bold text when some words or characters in a String wrapped with special characters such as ++bold++ displaying as **bold** with Jetpack Compose `Text` component as many times it's available in a specific string.

```
val boldRegex = Regex("\\*\\*.*\\*\\*")
```

using this regex and the snippet below

```
@Composable
fun CustomText(text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {


    val boldKeywords: MatchResult? = boldRegex.find(text)

    val boldIndexes = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()
    boldKeywords?.let {
        boldIndexes.add(Pair(it.range.first, it.range.last - 2))
    }

    val newText = text.replace("**", "")

    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        append(newText)

        // Add bold style to keywords that has to be bold
        boldIndexes.forEach {
            addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color(0xff64B5F6),
                    fontSize = 15.sp

                ),
                start = it.first,
                end = it.second
            )

        }
    }

    Text(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp),
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        text = annotatedString
    )
}
```

[image]

I get the result right only when an exact pattern exists once and not also it's not correct replacing every occurrence of the character.

```
CustomText(text = "This is a **bold** text")

CustomText(
    text = "This is a **bold** text  and another **random** value build with *regex expression"
)

CustomText(
    text = "This is NOT a ****bold** text build with *regex expression"
)

CustomText(
    text = "This is NOT a **bold text build with *regex expression"
)
```

- In first text result is as desired
- In second one it should only make **bold** and **random** substrings as bold
- In third one it should not have any bold substrings and no
  replacement
- In fourth one there should be no bold substrings and no replacements

I checked this [regex question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686645/regex-between-a-specific-pattern) but i wasn't able to come up with correct regex to divide into groups and replacing pattern with

Comment: You probably want ``"(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*).*?(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*)"``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew's help with regex i came up with a solution but i don't think it's efficient as i expect it to be. If you come up with better solution feel free to add a new answer.

```
val boldRegex = Regex("(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*).*?(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*)")


@Composable
fun CustomText(text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var results: MatchResult? = boldRegex.find(text)

    val boldIndexes = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()

    val keywords = mutableListOf<String>()

    var finalText = text

    while (results != null) {
        keywords.add(results.value)
        results = results.next()
    }

    keywords.forEach { keyword ->
        val indexOf = finalText.indexOf(keyword)
        val newKeyWord = keyword.removeSurrounding("**")
        finalText = finalText.replace(keyword, newKeyWord)
        boldIndexes.add(Pair(indexOf, indexOf + newKeyWord.length))
    }

    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        append(finalText)

        // Add bold style to keywords that has to be bold
        boldIndexes.forEach {
            addStyle(
                style = SpanStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color(0xff64B5F6),
                    fontSize = 15.sp

                ),
                start = it.first,
                end = it.second
            )

        }
    }

    Text(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp),
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        text = annotatedString
    )
}
```

I think it can be solved without using a second loop but couldn't find it.

Result for

```
Column() {
    CustomText(text = "This is a **bold** text")

    CustomText(
        text = "This is a **bold** text and another **random** value **build** with *regex expression"
    )

    CustomText(
        text = "This is NOT a ****bold** text build with *regex expression"
    )

    CustomText(
        text = "This is NOT a **bold text build with *regex expression"
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications on you answer using less code and for loops, You may check this

```
val boldRegex = Regex("(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*).*?(?<!\\*)\\*\\*(?!\\*)")


@Composable
fun TextWithBoldStrings(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    regularFontSize: TextUnit = 16.sp,
    boldSpanStyle: SpanStyle = SpanStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        color = Color(0xff64B5F6),
        fontSize = 15.sp
    )
) {

    val keywords = boldRegex.findAll(text).map { it.value }.toList()

    val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
        var startIndex = 0
        keywords.forEach { keyword ->
            val indexOf = text.indexOf(keyword)
            append(text.substring(startIndex, indexOf))
            startIndex = indexOf + keyword.length
            val newKeyWord = keyword.removeSurrounding("**")
            withStyle(
                style = boldSpanStyle
            ) {
                append(newKeyWord)
            }
        }
        append(text.substring(startIndex, text.length))

    }

    Text(
        modifier = modifier,
        fontSize = regularFontSize,
        text = annotatedString
    )
}
```